# When applying (@@) a function to a list of potential arguments, how can Slot be used to take the last argument?

Tags: list-manipulation, slot

I wouldn't be surprised if the title question is confusing, so I'll try to elaborate by way of example.

Consider the list

```
person = {firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, occupation, ..., country}
```

where each element of `person` is a `String`. I have a larger list, `people`, consisting of all lists `person` containing varying amounts of information. All `person` lists include first and last names and country, but not all have the DOB or occupation. I don't particularly care about these latter two entries. Other `person` lists have even more information between `occupation` and `country` (denoted by `...`) that I would like to ignore.

I want to generate a list of pairs consisting of the `StringRiffle`d first and last names, and the country, so that each `person` list is transformed to

```
{fullName, country}
```

Getting the names set up is easy using `Slot`s, but I can't think of a good way to get the country in a consistent way. I had thought to try

```
{StringRiffle[{#1, #2}], #(-1)} & @@ # & /@ people
(* but the second entry is -1 times the first name ... *)
```

and

```
{StringRiffle[{#1, #2}], Slot[-1]} & @@ # & /@ people
(* but the argument to Slot must be non-negative ... *)
```

Is there some way of using `Slot` to this end? I'm of course open to other simpler suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already observed, `Slot[-1]` is not valid syntax in the same way as `Slot[1]`. The only way I can think of to do what you want, is to catch all arguments in a list with `SlotSequence` and then take the last `Part`:

```
{##}[[-1]] & @@ Range[5]
```

> 5

However, for stuff like this, I'd recommend using Associations instead, since then you can index by name instead of by integer positions and it's much easier to skip parts of the data:

```
people = {
   <|"FirstName" -> "John", "LastName" -> "Doe", "DoB" -> Yesterday, "Country" -> "Somewhere"|>
};
{StringRiffle[{#FirstName, #LastName}], #Country} & /@ people
```

> {{"John Doe", "Somewhere"}}

It makes it easier to understand the code as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
people = {
   {firstName1, lastName1, dateOfBirth1, occupation1, country1},
   {firstName2, lastName2, , occupation2, country2}, 
   {firstName3, lastName3, dateOfBirth3, , country3}};

{StringRiffle[#[[1 ;; 2]]], #[[-1]]} & /@ people

(* {{"firstName1 lastName1", country1}, {"firstName2 lastName2", 
  country2}, {"firstName3 lastName3", country3}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{StringRiffle[{#1, #2}], #3}& @@@ people[[All, {1,2,-1}]]
```

> {{John Doe, Canada}, {firstName2 lastName2, country2}, {firstName3 lastName3, country3}}

Alternatively:

```
{StringRiffle[{#2, #3}], #1}&@@@(RotateRight/@people)
```

**data**

```
people = {
          {John, Doe, dateOfBirth1, occupation1, Canada},
          {firstName2, lastName2, , occupation2, martialStatus,country2}, 
          {firstName3, lastName3, dateOfBirth3, martialStatus , sex, country3}
          };
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using the operator form of `Replace` for these tasks, because in those circumstances you can use patterns and give parts of the sequence names. If you must use the `@@`, you can compose with `List`:

```
List /* Replace[{firstName_, lastName_, ___, country_} :>
    {StringRiffle[{firstName, lastName}], country}] @@ 
 {"John", "Doe", "random", "dumb", "stuff", "Burkina Faso"}
(* {"John Doe", "Burkina Faso"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{"John", "Doe", "1986", "Baltimore", "USA"},
   {"Mary", "Higgins", "1974", "London", "UK"}};
```

Define pattern

```
p = {a_, b_, __, c_} :> {a <> " " <> b, c};
```

Apply it

```
Cases[p] @ list
```

{{"John Doe", "USA"}, {"Mary Higgins", "UK"}}

```
list /. p
```

{{"John Doe", "USA"}, {"Mary Higgins", "UK"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"John", "Doe", "1986", "Baltimore", "USA"},
        {"Mary", "Higgins", "1974", "London", "UK"}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{a_, b_, __, c_}} :> {a <> " " <> b, c}]

(*{{"John Doe", "USA"}, {"Mary Higgins", "UK"}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_, __, c_}} :> {a <> " " <> b, c}]

(*{{"John Doe", "USA"}, {"Mary Higgins", "UK"}}*)
```

Or using `MapApply` as follows:

```
{#1 <> " " <> #2, Last@{##}} & @@@ list

(*{{"John Doe", "USA"}, {"Mary Higgins", "UK"}}*)
```